# short story where a robot is built to maintain a bridge but blows it up

Tags: story-identification, robots

I heard someone talking about this in passing a few years back but he couldn't remember the name

Comment: Is that all you know about the book? Did they say when it was written, or when they read it? If there was a picture on the cover? Was it hardcore Sci-Fi, or YA Sci-Fi? The more details you can supply, the likelier you'll get the answer to your question.

Comment: @major i believe the 70's but im not sure. im pretty sure it wasn't young adult sci fi(like teen in a postapocalyptic Orwellian dystopia) but the guy was 45 five years ago and said he read it when he was a teen

Comment: Well, I'm sure I don't know, but you'd be surprised what the folks on this site can do with a handful of details. +1 to you and welcome to SE SciFi&F.

Comment: Not quite what you're looking for, but Marvin (the Paranoid Android from Douglas Adams' work) sank a bridge he was suppose to be opening/dedicating.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the story but it does have a robot blowing up bridges its supposed to build; its written long enough ago; the text of the story is available online (I just read it); it popped up from someone's interview: novelette called **"For a Breath I Tarry"** by **Roger Zelazny** written in 1966: set in distant future, humanity is extinct, but our robots carry on tending humanity's infrastructure and attempt to become human; they blow up bridges and rebuild them in arguments over "perfect" siting.

Comment: @cybermike no i remember he said that people got mad at the robot and probed him for his motivation and i think sent him to robot jail but im not sure about the jail part. i know he was punished in some robot way